# Where are the Console Logs of Safari iOS Extension located?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, logging, safari-extension

I am building a Safari iOS (v15) extension, using HTML, CSS, and Javascript, in the XCode IDE.  But, where are the console logs located?

When the extension UI is running on an iOS device simulator then it is very hard to find the root cause without seeing the console log.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to see the logs of console.log("some message") they are indeed in the `Develop` -> `Show Web Inspector` menu in Safari. If you don't see `Develop` you will have to enable it in Preferences -> Advanced.

In order to see the `console.log` output of your extension's javascript, there are 2 things to note.

- console.log messages in `content.js` will be logged to the console where you usually see log output.
- However, if you want to see the log output of your `background.js` script you will need to do this:

  `Develop` -> `Web Extension Background Pages`, that will popup another console connected to your background.js.

[image: Web Extension Background Pages]

For a more thorough explanation see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70597271/348121

Answer (score 0):

You can use Safari on macOS to debug the extension running in the Simulator.

1. Enable Developer menu in Safari. (Safari - Preferences - Advanced tab -  "Show Develop meny in menu bar")
   2.In the Safari - Develop menu you'll be able to see what is running on your simulator(s) and select to debug it in Web Inspector.

Comment: It doesn't work. I can open the web inspector, but can't find any console.log() output in console tab.